# Impulse not showing some purchased but not installed applications

Tags: windows-7, windows, stardock, impulse

I'm using Windows 7, and i wanted to install Deskscapes, which i purchased as part of Object Desktop. However Deskscapes doesn't show up in the list. What's even more odd is it did show up in the list once but only until impulse finished connecting, then it disappeared. Does impulse not show items that can't be installed or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, some parts of their software don't support Windows 7 **yet**, as explained in this [forum topic](http://forums.impulsedriven.com/345620). It won't install if it doesn't meet the requirements (and Deskscape [doesn't support](http://www.stardock.com/products/deskscapes/) Windows 7 for now).

I'm guessing that in this case, it doesn't even show in the list. The fact it appears when it finishes to connect shows that you own it indeed, but it chose to not display it as "installable".

In general, remember that Object Desktop applications are mostly about modifying the appearance and way to behave of the Windows environment. That explains why it requires some time before all programs are working, with the new desktop provided by Windows 7.